# why do I get duplicated menu items in emacs dired mode

Tags: emacs, dired

I have two menu items for dir, mark, regexp, multiple and single on the menu bar in dired mode. While it doesn't affect the usage, but it seems something is wrong and makes me feel uncomfortable. Anyone know what is the cause?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What @Stefan said. The likely cause is some code you are loading that adds a new menu (e.g. `Dir`) instead of modifying an existing menu (e.g., `Dir`). If the key that a menu is bound to is different (e.g. `[menu-bar my-menu]` instead of `[menu-bar subdir]`), but the menu name for that key is the same (e.g. `Dir`), then seeming duplication is the result.  Are the "duplicate" menus identical (real duplicates)? I'm guessing no.

Comment: Yes, it is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see this problem already with `emacs -Q`?
If not, then try to see which part of your config file triggers this problem.

Comment: It happens when evil mode is on otherwise it is good. I think I should create an issue on the evil main page.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else has the same issue. Here is the bug report
https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/404/dired-menus-are-duplicated